# Why do some use parallel arrays instead of array lists? Is there any real difference?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Just a question I have been thinking about for a while. Like why use something like this below instead of putting it in an array list?

```
    int student_id[]=new int[100];
    String stu_fname[]=new String[100];
    String stu_lname[]=new String[100];
    String stu_major[]=new String[100];
    double stu_gpa[]=new double [100];
```

Comment: These students should be objects of a Student class. I don't quite follow your proposal/tradeoff here. Note that the parallel processing tag doesn't seem to apply to this post.

Comment: Please also show the alternative code you are thinking of.